# edit a Vim macro with a range operation that refers to a tag

Tags: vim, vim-macros

I created a macro with a range (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges) operation like:

```
:.,'bs/ .*$\n/ /ge^M
```

I then wanted to edit it, which I would normally do using let (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros#Editing_a_macro):

```
:let @b=':.,'bs/ .*$\n/ /ge^Mdd'
```

But for these examples, the ' in the macro definition causes the edit to fail.  How to resolve this?  Either an alternate range syntax or a way to escape the quote when defining.

I know I can re-record the macro, but the actual version is much longer than this!

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: gah! Thanks!  If you drop it in as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Single quotes need to be doubled inside such string: `:let @b=':.,''bs/ .*$\n/ /ge^Mdd'`
- You could use double quotes, but then also double backslashes (if there are any) `:let @b=":.,'bs/ .*$\\n/ /ge^Mdd"`
- Instead of `:let`, you could `:put b` into a scratch buffer, edit, then `"by$` into the register again.